# Leer a partir de un delimitador en un fichero

Tags: c++, xml, entrada

verán, estoy leyendo un fichero xml donde cada entrada tiene el siguiente formato:

```
<BatchIdentifier>[ID_FACTURA]</BatchIdentifier>
```

Yo capturo cada  línea en el fichero con:

```
string line;

while(getline(plantilla,line,'\n')){//PARA HACER LO MISMO CON CADA LINEA DEL FICHERO

    while() 
}
```

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo leer a partir del corchete que abre y terminar de leer en el que cierra?, si existe alguna función para empezar a leer a partir de un delimitador porque obviamente, lo que está al principio y al final de esa línea son etiquetas de `xml`, solo interesa almacenar lo que está en medio

Se agradece ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Este es una aplicacion muy particular y yo pienso que existen muchas librerias que realizan esa tarea, ahorrate el tiempo y usalas.

Comment: @eyllanesc precisamente por esas librerias estoy preguntando, la pregunta es clara, dime alguna librería si sabes de muchas que realizan esa tarea

Comment: ¿y por que no haces una simple busqueda en google?

Comment: @eyllanesc, ¿Y por qué te imaginas que yo no he buscado nada en google antes de preguntar aquí? claro que he buscado y mucho antes de pasar por stackoverflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auto it    = std::find(line.begin(),line.end(),'>');
auto itEnd = std::find(it,line.end(),'<');
std::string factura(std::next(it,1),itEnd);
```

Puedes verlo funcionando <kbd>[aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MIj2722iWozfO1Y8)</kbd>

Comment: Gracias, de todos modos había logrado encontrar una forma de leer a partir de un delimitador usando  el basic_string, uno de los constructores de la clase string de la stl, que me crea un string pasándole un iterador al comienzo y otro al final